# Giving error while installing the package in python

Tags: python

.As i am installing the pygooglenews using command "pip install pygooglenews"  giving me error ---- metadata-generation-failed""

I wanted to fetch news from google by using filter i.e If i will give name of any person, it would fetch news related to that person.

Comment: Please give the entire error

Comment: is the solution below works ? is it a accepted solution share the feed back

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately

pygooglenews 0.1.2 requires feedparser<6.0.0,>=5.2.1, but you have feedparser 6.0.10 which is incompatible. and the feedparser==5.2.1 has issue in meta data egg.info

to over come this you can acutally install pygooglenews without dependencies and you can install your own preferred configs like as follows

Step 1:

**download the tar file and extract in local:**

```
curl -O https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3f/d5/695ef6cd1da80e090534562ba354bc72876438ae91d3693d6bd2afc947df/pygooglenews-0.1.2.tar.gz
```

**extract:**

```
tar -xvzf pygooglenews-0.1.2.tar.gz
```

**move into the directory:**

```
cd pygooglenews-0.1.2
pip install pygooglenews --no-deps
```

**install all the deps one by one manually :**

```
 pip install feedparser --force
 pip install beautifulsoup4 --force
 pip install  dateparse --force
 pip install requests --force
```

you are ready to use the pygooglenews now